# Issue with Quantile Regression at the 75th Percentile in R

Tags: r, percentile, quantile-regression, quantreg

I’m encountering an issue when performing quantile regression in R. The process works fine for the lower percentiles, but I do not receive any output when attempting to run it for the 75th percentile. Instead, I receive the error message that singular matrix is backsolve. This suggests a problem with a singular matrix (though I am not sure if it really is. Moreover, I've checked the Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) for my variables to identify and it says that the categorical variables has high multicollinearity. Can anyone help me how to fix this? Any further suggestions would be appreciated.